# CampaignMember and Platform Encryption - Unable to encrypt fields

Tags: campaign-member, platform-encryption, shield-encryption

There are multiple fields within the CampaignMember object that I would like to, and should be, encrypted. For example, FirstName, LastName, Email, etc. Is there a reason I can't encrypt these?  My assumption is they aren't truely "stored" on the CampaignMember object(due to it being a junction object).  However, I have been wrong before(a few times)! Does anyone have a definitive answer on why no fields on this object can be encrypted?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: these fields are essentially formula fields on CampaignMember and hence are derived from Lead and Contact fields. As such, there is no need to do encryption-at-rest of these formula fields as they don't occupy disk space

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because these fields on [CampaignMember](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_campaignmember.htm?search_text=campaignmember) are neither creatable or updateable they are essentially formula fields and as such, Shield Platform encryption does not apply (as this is a feature for encryption at rest - protecting against the disks being stolen or copied at a bit level by a bad guy)

> LastName   Type string
>
> Properties Filter, Group, Nillable, Sort
>
> Description The last name of the contact or lead. Limit is 80
>   characters.

Note that for OOTB fields that **are** creatable/updateable, not all of them are enabled for Shield Platform encryption. In a discussion I had recently with the PM, SFDC is working incrementally towards expanding the list release-by-release.

Comment: Thanks @cropredy! Awesome Information.